# Catching exceptions by generators inside `for` loop

Tags: python, exception, generator

I want to write decorator for generators that will catch all exceptions inside `for` loop, process them and *continues* loop.

I wrote this decorator (for Django 1.5 ORM):

```
def savepoint_loop(generator, uniq_error_in='_uniq'):
    with commit_on_success():
        sp = savepoint()
        for obj in generator:
            try:
                yield obj
            except DatabaseError as e:
                if uniq_error_in not in e.args[0]:
                    raise
                savepoint_rollback(sp)
                yield None
            else:
                savepoint_commit(sp)
                sp = savepoint()
```

And I use it like:

```
loop = savepoint_loop(offer.booking_data.iteritems())
for provider_name, booking_data in loop:
    try:
        BookingData.objects.create(
            offer=pnr_offer, provider=provider_name, **booking_data)
    except Exception as e:
        loop.throw(e)
```

But it doesn't looks Pythonic. It allows me to make my code DRY, but looks confusing.
Is there any way to make it cleaner? At least I want to remove try-except-throw construction or change it to `with` operator.

Ideally it should look like this:

```
for provider_name, booking_data in savepoint_loop(
        offer.booking_data.iteritems()):
    BookingData.objects.create(
         offer=pnr_offer, provider=provider_name, **booking_data)
```

Comment: The generator does not "know" whether you happen to run a for-loop code block with the value you get from it, so there's no way to get the code you ask for.  I think your first code example (what you're currently doing) would be clearer if you forget about wrapping the generator (with a "decorator") and just put your rollback code directly in the `except` block, or write a function with the rollback code and call that from the `except` block.

Comment: Why do you have a `yield None`? That's going to cause a TypeError when the assignment to `provider_name, booking_data` fails.

Comment: No, calling `throw()` method requests getting next value from generator (like the `next()` method). So these `yield None` will be yielded into `loop.throw(e)`, and next value of source generator will be yielded into `for` line.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def error_processor(uniq_error_in='_uniq'):
    sp = savepoint()
    try:
        yield
    except DatabaseError as e:
        if uniq_error_in not in e.args[0]:
            raise
        savepoint_rollback(sp)
    else:
        savepoint_commit(sp)
```

This is a context manager that should do the job your coroutine does, but hopefully in a more understandable manner. You'd use it as follows:

```
with commit_on_success():
    for provider_name, booking_data in offer.booking_data.iteritems():
        with error_processor():
            BookingData.objects.create(
                offer=pnr_offer, provider=provider_name, **booking_data)
```

I couldn't fit the `commit_on_success` into the context manager, as the `commit_on_success` needs to go around the `for` loop, but the error handling needs to go inside the loop.

Comment: This solution is the closest to the ideal variant.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I think I see why this isn't straightforward. Any loop over an iterable basically comprises the following steps:

1. initialization
2. check termination condition
3. get next element
4. execute body of loop
5. ... repeat steps 2-4 until the termination condition is satisfied

In a Python `for` loop, steps 2 and 3 are encapsulated in the `for x in y` statement. But it sounds like you want to use the same `try...except` to catch exceptions in steps 3 and 4. So it would appear that this will require you to "decompose" the `for` statement, i.e. implement it manually using a `while` loop instead.

```
iterable = offer.booking_data.iteritems() # step 2
try:
    while True:
        try:
            provider_name, booking_data = iterable.next() # step 3
            BookingData.objects.create(...) # step 4
        except:
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

I'm sure you would agree that this is stylistically worse than the code sample you already have in your question, with `try...except` inside the `for` loop. Sure, it's conceivable that it might be useful, if you really need steps 3 and 4 to be inside the same `try` block, but I would imagine cases like that are rare.

It's also possible there is some sneaky way to construct a generator that does what you want, but I can't think of one.